# Individual Captions on adjacent tables

Tags: tables, captions

I have two adjacent tables, how can i give them a separate caption, or even a caption at all?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
\hline
\textbf{UnionCard} & \textbf{Kosten} \\
\hline
Jaarkaart & €50 \\
Verenigingsheffing jaar & €22,50 \\
& \\
1e boete kaart & €150 \\
2e boete kaart & €200 \\
incl. aanschaf & €50 \\
& \\
1e boete heffing & €5 \\
2e boete heffing & €10 \\
incl. aanschaf & €22,50 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
\hline
\textbf{CampusCard} & \textbf{Kosten} \\
\hline
Jaarkaart & €100 \\
Verenigingsheffing jaar & €60 \\
& \\
1e boete kaart & €300 \\
2e boete kaart & €400 \\
incl. aanschaf & €100 \\
& \\
1e boete heffing & €15 \\
2e boete heffing & €30 \\
incl. aanschaf & €60 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Global caption}
    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{individual caption}
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
    \hline
    \textbf{UnionCard} & \textbf{Kosten} \\
    \hline
    Jaarkaart & €50 \\
    Verenigingsheffing jaar & €22,50 \\
    & \\
    1e boete kaart & €150 \\
    2e boete kaart & €200 \\
    incl. aanschaf & €50 \\
    & \\
    1e boete heffing & €5 \\
    2e boete heffing & €10 \\
    incl. aanschaf & €22,50 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{individual caption}
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
    \hline
    \textbf{CampusCard} & \textbf{Kosten} \\
    \hline
    Jaarkaart & €100 \\
    Verenigingsheffing jaar & €60 \\
    & \\
    1e boete kaart & €300 \\
    2e boete kaart & €400 \\
    incl. aanschaf & €100 \\
    & \\
    1e boete heffing & €15 \\
    2e boete heffing & €30 \\
    incl. aanschaf & €60 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**OR**

With `minipages`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}

        \centering
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}\centering
            \caption{individual caption}
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
    \hline
    \textbf{UnionCard} & \textbf{Kosten} \\
    \hline
    Jaarkaart & €50 \\
    Verenigingsheffing jaar & €22,50 \\
    & \\
    1e boete kaart & €150 \\
    2e boete kaart & €200 \\
    incl. aanschaf & €50 \\
    & \\
    1e boete heffing & €5 \\
    2e boete heffing & €10 \\
    incl. aanschaf & €22,50 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}\centering
\caption{individual caption}
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
    \hline
    \textbf{CampusCard} & \textbf{Kosten} \\
    \hline
    Jaarkaart & €100 \\
    Verenigingsheffing jaar & €60 \\
    & \\
    1e boete kaart & €300 \\
    2e boete kaart & €400 \\
    incl. aanschaf & €100 \\
    & \\
    1e boete heffing & €15 \\
    2e boete heffing & €30 \\
    incl. aanschaf & €60 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility uses the `floatrow` package and its eponymous environment, which cooperates with `caption`  & friends. Here is an example code, where the two tables are independent. If they should be subtables, you can use the `subfloatrow` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[! ht]
\centering\floatsetup{floatrowsep=qquad}
    \begin{floatrow}[2]
\ttabbox{ \caption{First table caption} \label{1st tab}}
{\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
    \hline
    \textbf{UnionCard} & \textbf{Kosten} \\
    \hline
    Jaarkaart & €50 \\
    Verenigingsheffing jaar & €22,50 \\
    & \\
    1e boete kaart & €150 \\
    2e boete kaart & €200 \\
    incl. aanschaf & €50 \\
    & \\
    1e boete heffing & €5 \\
    2e boete heffing & €10 \\
    incl. aanschaf & €22,50 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}}
\ttabbox{\caption{Second table caption}\label{2nd tab}}
{\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
    \hline
    \textbf{CampusCard} & \textbf{Kosten} \\
    \hline
    Jaarkaart & €100 \\
    Verenigingsheffing jaar & €60 \\
    & \\
    1e boete kaart & €300 \\
    2e boete kaart & €400 \\
    incl. aanschaf & €100 \\
    & \\
    1e boete heffing & €15 \\
    2e boete heffing & €30 \\
    incl. aanschaf & €60 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{table}

We see in \cref{2nd tab} that…

\end{document}
```

[image]